# Dockerfile - Optional runtime parameter passed to command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, containers, command-line-interface

I need to pass optional, runtime parameter to a command in Docker.

The idea is that if PARAM env variable is set when docker is being run - it should be passed to java command as `--key VALUE` , and when runtime parameter is not set - it shoulddn't pass anything - in particular it shouldn't pass `--key` parameter name.

I.e. it should run following command if `PARAM` env variable is set:
`/bin/java -jar artifact.jar --key $PARAM`

And following if it's not:
`/bin/java -jar artifact.jar`

I wanted to use `:+` syntax, but it's resolved during build time, which means it won't be affected by runtime env variable.

```
docker build -t test-abc . && docker run -e "PARAM=oooo" test-abc
```

```
FROM openjdk:17

ENV PARAM=${PARAM:+"--key $PARAM"}


ENTRYPOINT /bin/java -jar artifact.jar $PARAM
```

Comment: It's probably easier and safer to make your program directly understand environment variables.  If you're using Spring Boot, it already knows how to translate environment variables to Spring properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare a script that will correctly handle arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
if [[ -v PARAM ]]; then
   args=(--key "$PARAM")
fi
/bin/java -jar artifact.jar "${args[@]}" "$@"
```

And add it:

```
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
CMD chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid that tbh, but thank you, I guess there's no way around this. 
Thank you

Comment: You can also do. `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "args=(); if [[ -v PARAM ]]; then args=(-- key \"$PARAM\".....", "_"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ENTRYPOINT` here, and you rewrite it in JSON-array syntax, then you can pass additional arguments to your program after the `docker run image-name`.  (Technically they replace the `CMD`.)

```bash
# Dockerfile: do use JSON-array syntax; do not attempt to handle options;
# must use ENTRYPOINT for "container-as-command" layout
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "artifact.jar"]
```

```bash
docker run test-abc --key oooo
```

You can also write the parameter expansion directly inside the command string.  This requires you to use shell-syntax `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, and so will essentially forbid you from providing extra options you don't set up this way.  The `${VARIABLE:+value}` syntax is supported in the POSIX specification so this should work with all Linux distribution base images, even if they don't include bash.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT java -jar artifact.jar ${PARAM:=--key "$PARAM"}
```

[BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has some more syntax suggestions, some of which are bash-specific, but the more detailed ones do require a good understanding of shell splitting and expansions.